# Is it possible to import Eclipse projects without .classpath files?

Tags: java, github, tomcat, import, project

I'm on process which connect Eclipse projects to Github

My projects has made as Dynamic web project

I uploaded my files on Github(using push) and cloned it on other computer

But as I know, When you share your project through your teammates,
you don't need to share .classpath or buildpath things..

so I maed my gitIgnore file from the website that I can make it
(used keywords 'Windows, Eclipse, Maven, Java ...')

Clone whole folder has done completely well, but after that when I tried to open my workspace
there is nothing and I cannot see my projects there.

so I tried all 'import project' menus but it says 'no projects found'

**
People here advised if there is no .classpath files you cannot import projects.
but Gitignore has those files to ignore.**

How can I import those projects without .classpath files .. ??

All import projects from.. menus

Comment: I think first you need to check the process to commit the project in git and which files can we include or not after that you will be able to checkout/share the project to others. hope this will help you or please share some steps or process how you committed the project on github.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import an "existing Maven project". This will use Maven's pom.xml to recreate Eclipse's required files (not only .classpath), and it's a good idea to do so (e.g. use maven or any other build tools), as your project can be built anywhere.

Comment: I tried this but Projects option behind Root Directory is still empty, even after I choose Root Directory